# UIActivityViewController Create Separate Mail icon

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to create a UIActivityViewController that lets the user send in feedback about the current web page that is being viewed. I want to have a separate button from the Mail icon to pop up with a compose window with a recipient set, subject set, and the message body to include some text and the current URL (I get the URL with: NSURL *urlStringToShare = _webView.request.URL; in the RootViewController). Any ideas how to do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, I already have an IBAction that does this:

```
- (IBAction)showEmail:(id)sender {
    // Email Subject
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Feedback on your latest column from the GlennKessler App:";
    // Email Content
    NSString *messageBody3 = @"I disagree with your latest Fact Check and the number of pinocchios you gave. This is what I would rate it instead and why:";
    // To address
    NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"blah@la.com"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody3 isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

    // Present mail view controller on screen
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Any way to convert this into a UIActivityViewController item with an icon? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, You can create a number of Custom Activityies such as mail using the Library found at this link:

https://github.com/imulus/OWActivityViewController